# iOS Universal Linking is not Working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, universal

I having the Universal linking in my application.

I place my Association file code into the server with the help of backend 
Please find My URL: https://www.furnitureinfashion.net/apple-app-site-association/

Whenever I check the domain validation here: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/?domain=https:%2F%2Fdevapp.meet2talk.com#resultsbox

It will show everything is fine, but when I pick on my base URL in safari it cants working.

Anyone suggest to me how do we resolve this issue.

I write the following delegate method in AppDelegate

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                        continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                        restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool
       {
           if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
               let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
               let userurl = url.absoluteString
            print(userurl)

        }
        return true
    }
```

Here I add the App Capabilities also.
[Capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANRrd.png)

Comment: Did you add the Associated Domains Entitlement in your project:
To set up the entitlement in your app, open the project’s Capabilities tab and enable Associated Domains. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains_in_your_app. Also Apple recommends to put the site-association file in .well-known folder instead of the root of the website. https://<fully qualified domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Comment: Also just entering the url in the browser might be ignored by universal linking, try opening the link from messages or notes for example.